# How can I process events of a used class?

Tags: vb.net, event-handling

I am still in the process of re-thinking from VB6 to .Net, so please forgive if this is trivial.

In a class I have properties which can change, and when they do they should raise a `Changed` event.

```
Public Class CPT
    Public Event Changed()

    Private gsText As String

    Public Property Text() As String
        Get
            Return gsText
        End Get
        Set(ByVal sValue As String)
            If sValue <> gsText Then
                gsText = sValue
                RaiseEvent Changed()
            End If
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

Another class features an `Add` method, in which it adds new items of above class into a collection.

```
Public Class UFB
    Private goTexts As New Dictionary(Of String, CPT)

    Public Sub Add(sKey As String, sText As String)
        Dim oPT As New CPT

        oPT.Text = sText
        goTexts.Add(sKey, oPT)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Obviously, `UFB` objects can not receive `Changed` events, because `oPT` is not declared on module level and thus can not feature `WithEvents`.

What is the .Net way to enable `UFB` to listen to `CPT`'s `Changed` events (which appear in many other `CPT` properties).

Comment: Firstly, I recommend that you [read this](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com.au/2009/11/defining-and-raising-custom-events.html). Next, I suggest that you rad the documentation for the `AddHandler` operator.

Comment: @VisualVincent, the `UPT` instance is aware of the `CPT` instance. For one thing, it creates it. For another, it's stored in the `Dictionary` assigned to `goTexts`.

Comment: `WithEvents` and `Handles` is just one way to register an event handler. In that case, the event handler follows the variable, i.e. if a new object is assigned to the variable then the event of the new object is now handled and the old one is not. The other way is with `AddHandler`, in which case the event handler follows the object, i.e. the event of that object will be handled until you use `RemopveHandler` regardless of what object is assigned to what variable in the interim.

Comment: @jmcilhinney : You're right, I missed that. Should've read the code more thoroughly. ;)

Comment: The WithEvents keyword is a bit of a trap.  It empowers the compiler to auto-generate a bunch of code that cooks the dinner, does the dishes and puts out the trash.  But it is not universal enough to work in all kitchens.  Not in this one.  You need the get back to basic vegetables and use the AddHandler, RemoveHandler and RaiseEvent statements.  They are well-documented in the MSDN articles and many tutorials.

Comment: [Events (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/events/)